# Упорядочивание списка упорядоченных массивов в один

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Дано: список массивов, каждый из которых упорядочен (для определенности, целых чисел и по возрастанию)

Нужно составить из этих массивов один, который будет также упорядочен

Для примера ((1,4,6) (2, 5, 8) ,(3, 9, 12)   ) -> (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,12)

Главное условие - сортировка должна быть максимально быстрой по времени (на память пока ограничений нет), так как массивы будут порядка ~10^7-10^8 элементов, количество ~ 10 штук.

Решение в лоб: записать последовательно все в один массив и попробовать отсортировать быстрой или слиянием (частичное упорядочивание, возможно даст выигрыш при слиянии)

Но, возможно, на таких входных данных (как "отрезки" отсортированных элементов) есть "более быстрое" решение, с которым я прошу помочь, так как в данной задаче мне важен любой выигрыш по времени.

Comment: Слияние, разумеется. Сравнивайте в цикле текущие элементы сливаемых массивов, выбирайте среди них наименьший, записывайте в выходной массив и продвигайтесь на 1 в массиве, из которого «ушёл» элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно слияние.

Примерный алгоритм в вашем случае:

1. Заводите номер текущего элемента в каждом из массивов
2. Выбираем минимум из текущих.
3. Копируем его в выходной массив и сдвигаем текущий элемент.
4. Если все массивы закончились, выходим. Иначе возвращаемся в пункт 2.

Примерный ход алгоритма:

1. `(*1, 4, 6), (*2, 5, 8), (*3, 9, 12)`, звёздочкой отмечены текущие элементы.
2. Выбрали минимум среди текущих, это 1. Сдвигаем: `(1, *4, 6), (*2, 5, 8), (*3, 9, 12) -> (1)`.
3. Минимум = 2, сдвигаем: `(1, *4, 6), (2, *5, 8), (*3, 9, 12) -> (1, 2)`
4. Минимум = 3, сдвигаем: `(1, *4, 6), (2, *5, 8), (3, *9, 12) -> (1, 2, 3)`
5. Минимум = 4, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, *6), (2, *5, 8), (3, *9, 12) -> (1, 2, 3, 4)`
6. Минимум = 5, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, *6), (2, 5, *8), (3, *9, 12) -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`
7. Минимум = 6, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, 6)*, (2, 5, *8), (3, *9, 12) -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`
8. Минимум = 8, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, 6)*, (2, 5, 8)*, (3, *9, 12) -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)`
9. Минимум = 9, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, 6)*, (2, 5, 8)*, (3, 9, *12) -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9)`
10. Минимум = 12, сдвигаем: `(1, 4, 6)*, (2, 5, 8)*, (3, 9, 12)* -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12)`
11. Конец.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно!

Comment: @Wial: Пожалуйста!