# Слияние отсортированных массивов. Ошибка реализации

Tags: java

Слияние двух отсортированных массивов, на хабрахабре есть ссылка на курс 
там есть пример , но с ошибкой, задача устранить ошибку, я как считаю правильным её устранил, ссылка на пример вот:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUGe1bZxXnk&index=5&list=PLoij6udfBncjnzOYE12-oKjz3HNPHEr9X

Код:

```
public class Merger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int[] left = {2, 7, 9};
         int[] right = {0, 2, 4};

         int[] result = new int [left.length + right.length];

         int leftIndex = 0;
         int rightIndex = 0;

         while (leftIndex + rightIndex !=result.length){
             if( left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]){
                 result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = left[leftIndex++];
                 if (leftIndex > left.length){   \\моё решение
                     leftIndex--;                \\моё решение
                 }
             }else{
                 result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = right[rightIndex++];
                 if(rightIndex > right.length){  \\моё решение
                     rightIndex--;               \\моё решение
                 }
             }
         }
         for(int i = 0; i <  result.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(result[i] + "  ");  
         }
    }
}
```

Алгоритм такой же как здесь:

[Упорядочивание списка упорядоченных массивов в один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472931/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Comment: а где индекс увеличивается хотя бы 1 раз?

Comment: @Pavel он увеличивается если не входит в    
             if (leftIndex > left.length){  
                 leftIndex--;               
             }

Comment: то что помечено ваше решение, проблема в том, что если мы дошли до конца списка, то мы заполним весь остаток последним элементом. Лучше вместо всех ваших строк, просто дописать ВЕСЬ остаток из 2 списка. Или чтобы было проще, вообще их убрать и добавить в конец каждого списка очень большое число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашёл здесь :
 http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread941205.html

Решение:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Merger {

    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int aIndex = 0;
        int bIndex = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < result.length) {
            result[i] = a[aIndex] < b[bIndex] ? a[aIndex++] : b[bIndex++];
            if (aIndex == a.length) {
                System.arraycopy(b, bIndex, result, ++i, b.length - bIndex);
                break;
            }
            if (bIndex == b.length) {
                System.arraycopy(a, aIndex, result, ++i, a.length - aIndex);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 16 };
        int[] b = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

        int[] rezult = merge(a, b);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rezult));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Сырая реализация:**

```
 int[] left = {2, 7, 9};
 int[] right = {0, 2, 4};

 int[] result = new int [left.length + right.length];

 int leftIndex = 0;
 int rightIndex = 0;

 while (leftIndex + rightIndex < result.length) {
     if(rightIndex==right.length || leftIndex != left.length
                          && left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]) {
         result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = left[leftIndex++];
     } else {
         result[leftIndex + rightIndex] = right[rightIndex++];
     }
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i] + "  ");  
 }
```

**Результат:**

> 0  2  2  4  7  9

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] fst, int[] snd) {
        int[] result = new int[fst.length + snd.length];
        int fstIndex = 0;
        int sndIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;

        while (fstIndex<fst.length && sndIndex<snd.length){

            if(fst[fstIndex]<snd[sndIndex]){
                result[index]=fst[fstIndex];
                fstIndex++;
            }
            else{
                result[index]=snd[sndIndex];
                sndIndex++;
            }
            index++;
        }

        while (fstIndex<fst.length){
            result[index]=fst[fstIndex];
            fstIndex++;
            index++;
        }

        while (sndIndex<snd.length){
            result[index]=snd[sndIndex];
            sndIndex++;
            index++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё возмозможный вариант решения:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] fst, int[] snd) {
    int[] result = new int[fst.length + snd.length];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k != result.length; k += 1) {
        if((i != fst.length) && (j == snd.length)) {
            result[k] = fst[i++];
            continue;
        }
        if((i != fst.length) && (j != snd.length)) {
            if((fst[i] < snd[j])) {
                result[k] = fst[i++];
                continue;
            } else {
                result[k] = snd[j++];
                continue;
            }
        }
        if((i == fst.length) && (j != snd.length)) {
            result[k] = snd[j++];
            continue;
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант решения, более читаемый и удобный для понимания.

```
public class Merge {
public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int[] rsl = new int[left.length + right.length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int ll = left.length;
    int rl = right.length;
    // take elements from left and right arrays
    while (i < ll && j < rl) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            rsl[k++] = left[i++];
        } else {
            rsl[k++] = right[j++];
        }
    }
    // take remains elements from left array
    while (i < ll) {
        rsl[k++] = left[i++];
    }
    // take remains elements from right array
    while (j < rl) {
        rsl[k++] = right[j++];
    }
    return rsl;
}
```

}